# Swift 4（Xcode 9.4） Alamo FireでMultipartFromDataを使用し画像送信したい

Tags: swift, swift4

プログラミング初心者です。初めて質問させて頂きます。
Swift 4（Xcode 9.4） Alamo FireでMultipartFromDataを使用し画像送信したいのですが、
提携の構文がわからず、お教えて頂けましたら幸いです。
宜しくお願いいたします。

```
import Alamofire

public func uploadMultipartFromData(parameters: [[String: Any]]) {
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
    let urlRequest = URL(string: url)!
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "name": "value"
    ]

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "str_param": "str value",
        "num_param": 0,
        "nested": [
            "nested_param": "value"
        ]
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: parameters,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: headers)
        .authenticate(user: "user", password: "password")
        .responseJSON { response in

            if
                let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
                let prop1 = json["prop1"] as? String
            {
                debugPrint(prop1)
            }

            debugPrint(response)
    }

    func appendMultipartFormData(multipartFormData: MultipartFormData, element: [String: Any]) {
    switch element["value"] {
    case let image as UIImage:
        var imageData: Data
        var mimeType: String
        if element["extension"] as! String == "jpg" {
            print(element["extension"] as! String)
            imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!
            mimeType = "jpeg"
        } else {
            imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
            mimeType = "png"
        }
        multipartFormData.append(
            imageData,
            withName: element["key"] as! String,
            fileName: element["name"] as! String,
            mimeType: mimeType
        )
    default:
        let value = element["value"] as! String
        multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: element["key"] as! String)
        break
    }
}

    func uploaldMultipartProcess(upload: UploadRequest, completeNotificationName: NSNotification.Name) {
    upload
        .uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in
            let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
            print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
            print("Status code: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
    }

}
```

Comment: 「提携」は「定型」の間違いでしょうか？

Comment: cubick さん　早速ありがとうございます！大変失礼しました。「定型」の間違いです。